# All Radio button groups are click or not

Tags: .net, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

In ascx user control, a radiobuttonlist control is there:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="TrueFalse" runat="server" onclick="Radcheck();" 
                     Font-Bold="True"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">T</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">F</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In javascript, I want to check that all radiobuttonlist controls are checked. 
 It will called by an aspx page, which will have more than one radiobuttonlist control.
Please find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Radcheck(){
  var areAllChecked = true;
  $('#<%=this.TrueFalse.CLientID%> :radio').each(function(){
     if(!this.checked){
       areAllChecked = false;
       return ;
     }

  });

  return areAllChecked;

}
```

Comment: Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'ASP.controls_cps_truefalsecontrol_ascx' does not contain a definition for 'TrueFalse'

Comment: if your js code is in apsx page , you have to take different approach, in your user control a create a public property ClientID like this public string ClientId { get { return this.rueFalse.ClientID;}} and change your js code like this  $('#<%=this.yorUserControlId.ClientID%> :radio').each(function(){

Comment: Radiolist controls are coming dinamicly it is under datalist control